# problem with dependencies while installing ubuntu-sdk

Tags: 13.04, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk

I get this error while installing ubuntu-sdk on clean install of Ubuntu 13.04 64bit:

```
szymon@szymon-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
[sudo] password for szymon: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ubuntu-sdk : Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas ?

Output of sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130424)]/ raring main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

Output of `apt-get install qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova ubuntu-sdk`

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu : Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common but it is not going to be installed
 qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova : Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova-common but it is not going to be installed
                                   Recommends: cordovamobilespec but it is not installable
                                   Recommends: cordovaqt-runtime but it is not installable
```

Output of `apt-cache depends ubuntu-sdk qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu && apt-cache policy ubuntu-sdk qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu`

```
-cordova qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu
ubuntu-sdk
  Depends: click
  Depends: click-dev
  Depends: click-doc
  Depends: cordova-ubuntu-2.8
  Depends: cordova-ubuntu-2.8-dev
  Depends: cordova-ubuntu-2.8-examples
  Depends: libqt5qml-graphicaleffects
  Depends: libqt5sql5-sqlite
  Depends: libqt5svg5-dev
  Depends: libqt5v8-5-dev
  Depends: libqt5webkit5-dev
  Depends: libqt5xmlpatterns5-dev
  Depends: qmlscene
    qmlscene:i386
  Depends: qt3d5-dev
  Depends: qt5-default
  Depends: qtbase5-dev
  Depends: qtcreator
  Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu
  Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova
  Depends: qtdeclarative5-cordova-2.8-plugin
  Depends: qtdeclarative5-dev
  Depends: qtdeclarative5-dev-tools
    qtdeclarative5-dev-tools:i386
  Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin
  Depends: qtlocation5-dev
  Depends: qtmultimedia5-dev
  Depends: qtscript5-dev
  Depends: qtsensors5-dev
  Depends: qttools5-dev
  Depends: qttools5-dev-tools
  Depends: ubuntu-html5-theme
  Depends: ubuntu-ui-toolkit-examples
  Depends: ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme
    ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme:i386
  Recommends: libqt5webkit5-qmlwebkitplugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-folderlistmodel-plugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-localstorage-plugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-particles-plugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-qtaudioengine-plugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-qtmultimedia-plugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-qtsensors-plugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-window-plugin
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-xmllistmodel-plugin
  Conflicts: ubuntu-sdk:i386
qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova
  Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova-common
  Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu
  Recommends: <cordovamobilespec>
  Recommends: <cordovaqt-runtime>
  Conflicts: qtcreator-plugin-cordovaqt
  Conflicts: qtcreator-plugin-cordovaqt:i386
  Replaces: qtcreator-plugin-cordovaqt
    qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova
  Replaces: qtcreator-plugin-cordovaqt:i386
    qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova:i386
  Conflicts: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova:i386
qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu
  Depends: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-common
  Depends: ubuntu-ui-toolkit-doc
  Depends: ubuntu-ui-toolkit-examples
  Depends: android-tools-adb
  Depends: dh-make
  Depends: ubuntu-html5-theme
  Depends: click
  Depends: qtcreator
  Conflicts: <ubuntu-qtcreator-plugins>
  Conflicts: <ubuntu-qtcreator-plugins:i386>
  Replaces: <ubuntu-qtcreator-plugins>
    qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu
  Replaces: <ubuntu-qtcreator-plugins:i386>
    qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu:i386
  Conflicts: qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu:i386
ubuntu-sdk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.009~sdkppa~raring1~test6
  Version table:
     1.009~sdkppa~raring1~test6 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
     1.004 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages
qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu-cordova:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7.1-0ubuntu1~raring1~test18
  Version table:
     2.7.1-0ubuntu1~raring1~test18 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.7.1-0ubuntu1~raring1~test18
  Version table:
     2.7.1-0ubuntu1~raring1~test18 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
     2.7.0-0ubuntu3 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 1):

OK so its working fine today,

apparently there was problem with version numbers in PPA, more info on this bug which now been fixed can be found [here](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg03840.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You should add the following ppa as well:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-proper && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't help

Comment: I just edited my answer. Make sure you update after adding ppa.

Comment: Of course I did `sudo apt-get update` after running your first command.